# Evaluating $\int {{x^{1/6}+1}\over x^{7/6}+x^{5/4}}\operatorname d\!x $

Tags: calculus, integration

I just want you to tell me if the next integral is correct, if not I really would appreciate if you can tell me where is my mistake:

$$\int {{x^{1/6}+1}\over x^{7/6}+x^{5/4}}dx = \int {{x^{1/6}}\over x^{7/6}+x^{5/4}}dx + \int {1\over x^{7/6}+x^{5/4}}dx$$

then I use the substitution:

$$u^{24}=x\;,\;\;dx=24u^{23}du\;,\;\; x^{1/6}=u^{4}\;,\;\;x^{7/6}=u^{28}\;,\;\; x^{5/4}=u^{30}$$ hence:

$$\int {{24u^{27}}\over u^{28}+u^{30}}du + \int {24u^{23}\over u^{28}+u^{30}}du = 24\int {du\over u+u^{3}} + 24\int {du\over u^{5}+u^{7}}$$

then I solved $$24\int {du\over u+u^{3}}$$ by partial fractions = $$24[\int {A\over u}du +\int {Bu+C\over u^2+1}du]$$  and I had that $Au^2+A +Bu^2+Cu=1$ which implies that $A=1$, $B=-1$ and $C=0$ so:

$$24[\int {A\over u}du +\int {Bu+C\over u^2+1}du]= 24[\int {du\over u} + \int {-u\over u^{2}+1}du]$$= $$24[ln|u|-{ln(u^{2}+1)\over 2}]=12[ln{u^{2}\over u^{2}+1}]$$

then I solved $$24\int {du\over u^{5}+u^{7}}$$ I used the next substitution

$u=tanz$, $du=sec^{2}zdz$ ; $u^{5}+u^{7}=u^{5}(1+u^{2})$= $tan^{5}z(sec^{2}z)$ hence:

$$24\int {du\over u^{5}+u^{7}}$$

$$=24\int {sec^{2}zdz\over tan^{5}zsec^{2}z}$$

$$=24$\int cot^{5}zdz$$

$$=24\int cotzcot^{4}zdz$$

$$=24\int cotz(csc^{2}-1)^{2}dz$$

$$=24\int cotz(csc^{4}z-2csc^{2}z+1)dz$$

$$=24\int cotzcsc^{4}zdz-48\int cotzcsc^{2}zdz+24\int cotzdz$$

$$=24\int cotzcsczcsc^{3}zdz-48({-cot^{2}z\over 2})+24ln|sinz|$$

=($-24csc^{4}z\over 4$)-48($-cot^{2}z\over 2$)+24ln|$sinz$|

and therefore -6$csc^{4}z$+24$cot^{2}z$+24 ln|$sinz$|

using again $u=tanz$ and pythagorean theorem:

$-6csc^{4}z$+$24cot^{2}z$+24 ln|$sinz$|= $-6(u^{2}+1)^{2}\over u^{4}$ +$24\over u^{2}$ + $24ln|{u\over (u^{2}+1)^{1/2}}|$

and using $u^{24}=x$ then the solution of the integral is:

$$\int {{x^{1/6}+1}\over x^{7/6}+x^{5/4}}dx = 12ln|{x^{1/12}\over x^{1/12}+1}|+24ln|{x^{1/24}\over (x^{1/12}+1)^{1/+2}}|+{24\over x^{1/12}}-{6(x^{1/12}+1)^{1/2}\over x^{1/6}}+C$$

Comment: Did you differentiate the last line in order to check you get the integrand function?

Comment: I began editing your post to make it clearer. Continue on and use \sin z, etc. for the trigonometric functions.

Comment: yes but I didnt get the integrand function; but I also checked the procedure of the integral and I didnt find any mistake

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way.  First of all I would suggest that in this kind of problem it is usually not helpful to split up the integral: generally it just means you do twice the work.  (Of course I am not saying this is *always* true.)  So start as you have done by substituting $x=u^{24}$ to give
$$I=24\int \frac{u^4+1}{u^5+u^7}\,du\ .$$
Now just go for partial fractions straight away.  If you look carefully you can see that
$$u^4+1=(1-u^2+2u^4)(u^2+1)-(2u)u^5\rlap{\kern50pt (*)}$$
and so
$$I=24\int \frac{u^4+1}{u^5(1+u^2)}\,du=24\int \frac{1-u^2+2u^4}{u^5}-\frac{2u}{u^2+1}\,du\ .$$
This is now an easy integral.

**Addendum**.  With a bit of care you can get $(*)$ by inspection, no need to solve lots of equations.  I started with
$$u^4+1=(\cdots)(u^2+1)+(\cdots)u^5\ .$$
Then I put $1$ in the first bracket to match the $1$ on the left hand side:
$$u^4+1=(1+\cdots)(u^2+1)+(\cdots)u^5\ .$$
But then I have a $u^2$ on the RHS which I don't want, so put in a $-u^2$:
$$u^4+1=(1-u^2+\cdots)(u^2+1)+(\cdots)u^5\ .$$
Eventually this gives
$$u^4+1=(1-u^2+2u^4\cdots)(u^2+1)+(\cdots)u^5\ ,$$
and now to make everything work I need $-2u$ in the second bracket and nothing else in the first:
$$u^4+1=(1-u^2+2u^4)(u^2+1)+(-2u)u^5\ .$$

Comment: thanks a lot david :D I think a did a lot of work for an easy integral

Comment: David I really appreciate your help, I will do this again thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

I took the derivative of your result but I am afraid I did not arrive to the integrand. So, instead of trying to find where there has been a mistake, I started from scratch.

If you reduce all exponents to same denominator, it becomes quite clear that the integrand only contains integer powers of $x^{1/12}$. So, I started with a change of variable $$x=y^{12}$$ Doing so, after replacements and simple simplifications, the integrand becomes quite simple and write $$\frac{12 \left(y^2+1\right)}{y^3 (y+1)}$$ which looks slightly simpler. Integrating with respect to $y$, the result I obtained, after using decomposition in partial fractions, is $$12 \left(-\frac{1}{2 y^2}+\frac{1}{y}+2 \log (y)-2 \log (y+1)\right)$$

Comment: thanks for the help Claude :D I will do it again